# Does Access Control lists override group or owner permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, acl, umask

I came across the following task:

> **Add 3 new users - alice, bob, charles**

- Create a new group - marketing - and add alice, bob and charles to
  that group
- Create a directory - /marketing - whose owner is alice and group is
  marketing
- Set appropriate permissions so that the marketing group can share
  documents in the new directory but nobody else can see the documents.
- Give charles read-only permission.
- Create an empty file in /marketing named "empty".

Here is my answer:

- useradd alice
- useradd bob
- useradd charles
- mkdir /marketing
- chown alice:marketing /marketing
- chmod g=rwx,o=x /marketing
- setacl -m  u:charles:r  d /marketing
- touch /marketing/empty

I guess I got everything right except to give charles only read permissions.

As you can see in my answer I did using acls, however, since charles is also the marketing group, i believe it ignores the acls, because I switches to user Charles and I was able to create a file in /marketing.

That makes me question if the task itself doesn't make sense!

or do i have to remove charles from the marketing group?

Comment: Which OS is this? That should work (and it does on, e.g., Linux and with `setfacl`, at least on an ACL-capable filesystem). But POSIX never finished an ACL standard, so there isn't actually a standard behavior. (And you want `rx` not just `r`)

Comment: This is centos 7

Comment: Then it should work. What is `setacl`? Do you mean `setfacl`? In which case you've got a mistake in the syntax.

Comment: (Try `setfacl -m u:charles:rx /marketing` — presumably Charles should be able to access the directory and its contents, not just list them, hence the `x` as well)

Comment: @derobert You are correct, the POSIX ACL proposal from 1993 has been withdrawn in 1997. Modern OS use the ACL definitions from the NFSv4 standard that is bitwise identical to NTFS ACLs.